# How to Make RStudio Presentation Self-contained?

Tags: r, rstudio, presentation, rpres

I'm writing a presentation in R using RStudio. To create new presentation, I select "R Presentation" from the File => New File menu. RStudio creates new document. Here is the template:

````
New Presentation
========================================================
author: 
date: 

First Slide
========================================================

For more details on authoring R presentations click the
**Help** button on the toolbar.

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

Slide With Code
========================================================

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

Slide With Plot
========================================================

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

Once a presentation is created, it can be saved as an HTML. However, I cannot find an option to make it a self-contained HTML file.

As a counter-example, I can create a self-contained HTML file using Rmarkdown:

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
    ioslides_presentation:
      mathjax: local
      self_contained: false
---
```

Source: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html

What is the equivalent of this code in RStudio R Presentation?

Additionally, does anyone know why they did it both ways?

SOLVED (09/25/2017)! See Nova's answer below. Here is a screenshot to show how I did it:

[image]

Comment: Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will answer, but: I have found that the R presentation format is a bit limited - you may be able to do better with something like ioslides or slidy, both of which are also easy to author with RStudio, e.g. http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html

Comment: Thank you Ben, I thought that might be the case... Lets see if anyone comes up with an answer, otherwise I will just switch to ioslides as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to "export" the presentation to html by going to the "Presentation" tab in RStudio, clicking the gear shift icon where it says "More", and choosing "Save as Webpage". This saved a stand-alone .html file that works when I open it from a different folder location.

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you Nova! I'm adding a screenshot below my question, with reference to your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure when they added this functionality - perhaps it was added after you asked the question!